# Find $f''(2x)$ if $f'(x) = g(x + 1)$ and $g'(x) = h(x - 1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, function-and-relation-composition

> Find $f''(2x)$ if $f'(x) = g(x + 1)$ and $g'(x) = h(x - 1)$

Hello, I am stuck on the above problem.

Here's my work:

Differentiate once:

$$\frac{d}{dx} (f(2x)) = 2 \cdot f'(2x) \text{ (Chain Rule)}$$
$$= 2 \cdot g(2x + 1)$$

Differentiate twice:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(2 \cdot g(2x + 1))$$
$$=2 \cdot 2 \cdot h(2x + 1 - 1) \text{ (Chain Rule)}$$
$$= 4 \cdot h(2x)$$

The answer is $$h(2x)$$ (I think that chain rule is not applied in the correct solution.)

This problem makes me feel that my concept is weak :(

Can someone explain why I am wrong?

Thanks

Comment: $f''(2x)$ is not equal to $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[f(2x)]$

Comment: @SolubleFish Then what is it equal??

Comment: $f''(2x)$ is the second derivative of $f$ evaluated at $2x$. Compute the derivative first, and then replace your variable by $2x$

Comment: @SolubleFish That clears things up. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(f(2x))=4f''(2x)$, so if $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(f(2x))=4h(2x)$, then $f''(2x)=h(2x)$. You applied the chain rule perfectly, but be careful because $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(f(2x))\not=f''(2x)$

Comment: Is $f''(2x) = \frac{d^2}{d(2x)^2} (f(2x))$?

Comment: Better see it that way:  $(f(h(x))) '=h'(x) f'(h(x)) $,  and $(f(h(x)))''=h''(x)f'(h(x)) +(h'(x)) ^2f''(h(x)) $